# Generalizations of toric varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, quiver-varieties

I would like to know, whether the following quotient construction has been considered, or whether it makes sense:

One way to think of toric varieties is as a quotient of $\mathbb{C}^n$ (minus exceptional set) by a product of $\mathbb{C}^*$'s, giving different projective weights to the $n$ complex coordinates. Choosing the weights amounts to setting the representation of $\mathbb{C}^*$ under which a homogeneous coordinate transforms.
In the quiver GIT constructions, one also considers quotients by products of $GL$ groups. However, in that case the representations are always the trivial, fundamental or anti-fundamental representations, since quiver arrows don't allow for more.

Are there constructions where one uses more general representations of $GL$ to create such quotients?

Comment: Sure: for any complex reductive group G and any linear representation V of G, you can consider the GIT quotient G//V (which in general can be twisted by a choice of character of G). Toric varieties are obtained for G a torus (product of $\mathbb{C}^{*}$) and quiver varieties for G a product of linear groups and V made of fundamentals and anti-fundamentals.

Comment: Has this been used explicitly for the resolved du Val singularities? I have seen those described via quiver GIT, but then those spaces require preprojective algebras of quadratic relations. I always suspected this was due to the limitation in representations used in quivers. For instance, the A series can be treated torically, without resort to relations if one allows for more general reps. Could the D and E series be treated as "appropriate" (meaning not using the (anti-)fundamental)) quotients of GL groups?